# What configuration is needed to include empty SOAP body parameters in Apache CXF?

Tags: java, soap, cxf

Apache CXF by default does not send empty SOAP body parameters (elements). How can CXF be configured to include these as self-closing/empty tags?

It may be because this particular web service marks the elements as Optional, but when the parameters are left out entirely, the service complains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in my case was that I was sending null values, and I needed to change this to be empty values instead.